# Magento 2 How to resize product gallery images?

Tags: magento2.2, product-images, image-resizing

I have to resize the product gallery images.

I'm using this link to resize image 
[Resize Image](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-change-product-image-size-magento-2.html)

but it's only allow to resize image product_base_image. While I have to resize all other image then base image.

I'm getting all images by

> $images = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();

it's give me images data as

```
Array
(
[value_id] => 3424
[file] => //w/b/wb01-black-0_1.jpg
[media_type] => image
[entity_id] => 14
[label] => 
[position] => 3
[disabled] => 0
[label_default] => 
[position_default] => 3
[disabled_default] => 0
[video_provider] => 
[video_url] => 
[video_title] => 
[video_description] => 
[video_metadata] => 
[video_provider_default] => 
[video_url_default] => 
[video_title_default] => 
[video_description_default] => 
[video_metadata_default] => 
[url] => http://192.168.1.174/magento2261/pub/media/catalog/product/w/b/wb01-black-0_1.jpg
[id] => 3424
[path] => D:/xampp/htdocs/magento2261/pub/media/catalog/product/w/b/wb01-black-0_1.jpg
)
```

Comment: Try run this php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

Comment: Have you edited your theme/etc/view.xml file to update the height and width for product_page_more_views then run the above command

Comment: I want to resize only on the details page programatically.

Comment: @Magecode take a look at https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/resize-custom-image-in-magento-2/

Comment: @DavaGordon it's not custom image. It's product gallery images

Comment: @Magecode shouldnt matter if custom or product image as long as its a relative path to the image it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento default image resize command.

To resize image please follow the steps below.

Assume You are using a custom them name "Conpany_MyTheme"

**step 1:** create the xml file **view.xml** under **MAGENTOROOT/app/design/frontend/Company/MyTheme/etc**

**FIle:** view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="bundled_product_customization_page" type="thumbnail">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_cross_sell_products" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_page_product_thumbnail" type="small_image">
                <width>165</width>
                <height>165</height>
            </image>
            <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>800</width>
                <height>800</height>
            </image>
            <image id="category_page_grid-1" type="small_image">
                <width>800</width>
                <height>800</height>
            </image>
            <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
                <width>800</width>
                <height>800</height>
            </image>
            <image id="customer_account_my_tags_tag_view" type="small_image">
                <width>100</width>
                <height>100</height>
            </image>
            <image id="customer_account_product_review_page" type="image">
                <width>285</width>
                <height>285</height>
            </image>
            <image id="customer_shared_wishlist" type="small_image">
                <width>113</width>
                <height>113</height>
            </image>
            <image id="gift_messages_checkout_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="gift_messages_checkout_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>100</width>
                <height>100</height>
            </image>
            <image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="new_products_content_widget_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="new_products_content_widget_list" type="small_image">
                <width>270</width>
                <height>340</height>
            </image>
            <image id="new_products_images_only_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>78</width>
                <height>78</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_base_image" type="image">
                <width>265</width>
                <height>265</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_comparison_list" type="small_image">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_image_large" type="image"/>
            <image id="product_page_image_large_no_frame" type="image">
                <frame>false</frame>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
                <width>700</width>
                <height>560</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_image_medium_no_frame" type="image">
                <width>1500</width>
                <height>1500</height>
                <frame>false</frame>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
                <width>88</width>
                <height>110</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
                <width>700</width>
                <height>560</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
                <width>700</width>
                <height>560</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_more_views" type="thumbnail">
                <width>88</width>
                <height>110</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_stock_alert_email_product_image" type="small_image">
                <width>76</width>
                <height>76</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>135</width>
                <height>135</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_thumbnail_image" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_compared_products_grid_content_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_compared_products_images_names_widget" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_compared_products_images_only_widget" type="thumbnail">
                <width>76</width>
                <height>76</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_compared_products_list_content_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>270</width>
                <height>340</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_viewed_products_grid_content_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_viewed_products_images_names_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_viewed_products_images_only_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>76</width>
                <height>76</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_viewed_products_list_content_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>270</width>
                <height>340</height>
            </image>
            <image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
                <width>152</width>
                <height>190</height>
            </image>
            <image id="hotpicks_products_list" type="small_image">
                <width>400</width>
                <height>400</height>
            </image>
            <image id="review_page_product_image" type="small_image">
                <width>285</width>
                <height>285</height>
            </image>
            <image id="rss_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="sendfriend_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="shared_wishlist_email" type="small_image">
                <width>135</width>
                <height>135</height>
            </image>
            <image id="side_column_widget_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="upsell_products_list" type="small_image">
                <width>600</width>
                <height>600</height>
            </image>
            <image id="wishlist_sidebar_block" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="wishlist_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>113</width>
                <height>113</height>
            </image>
            <image id="wishlist_thumbnail" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

You can mention image sizes with their XML entity name in the view.xml file

**product_page_main_image**
**product_page_main_image_default**
**product_page_more_views**

step 2: Run the CLI command from the Magento root.

```
sudo php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Note: Depending on your requirement you can delete other media XML entity like **bundled_product_customization_page**, **cart_cross_sell_products** etc